# One user gets a System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: provider-hosted-app, access-denied, high-trust-app

Hi I've built a high trust web application for our on prem SharePoint 2016. On the whole it works fine, however one user who only works as and when needed (so once every few weeks) seems to have a slight issue with the application.

The inital load always gives her a `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`. Error. This then goes and all works ok, until next time.

Is there something I should be looking at?
I've checked the 2 TokenHelper and SharePointContext files and both look ok with the token having a lifetime of 12hours.

I don't know for certain, but presume that we do have similar other staff (it's a large organisation) working similar patterns without mishap.

**Update**
So looking further and the Account field - the starting i:0#.w|domain\login.
The login doesn't match the User name in the User Information.

Has anyone seen this and can advise. The sync seems to be working...

**Update 2**
Ok, so what we know is that the Account in my sharepoint site says

Account: i:0#w|domain\new.Login

User name: OLDLOGIN

Last Modifed: 10/03/2022 by System Account

The central admin had the Account as the OLDLOGIN - we have deleted that profile but the incremental sync hasn't worked / sorted anything. Slightly hoping tomorrow it'll be ok once the full update has kicked in.

Comment: On the initial load, has her previous token expired and therefore it is returning a 401 before issuing a new token on the second load?

Comment: perhaps but it doesn't seem to happen to anyone else - even I don't access this system that often but don't get this issue.

Comment: surely they access SharePoint more than that user though?

Comment: Some do, but like I said some don't. Maybe I need to do some more sluthing here - checking of cookies etc on my own machine could yield some results. Maybe check her 'path' via the IIS logs as well - could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Apologies for a late response, I admit that other stuff had come in. I've cleared my cookies and tried the same path my user with the error has - but no issues.

Comment: Found some more information - see the 'Update' in the question.

Comment: Sounds as though the user has changed their SAM account name, I don't think this would necessarily cause an issue as the SID shouldn't have changed.

Comment: Yeah TBH this is getting really bizzarr - I'll update the question